# How to versioning releases in Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

Is there a way to publish releases on `GitHub` using `Actions` with custom version numbers? Currently, I'm using `github.run_number` provided by [GitHub Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) and as mentioned in the docs:

```
github.run_number (string) - A unique number for each run 
of a particular workflow in a repository. This number begins
at 1 for the workflow's first run, and increments with each new run.
```

Not every run of my workflow creates a release (e.g. when a workflow fails), resulting in inconsistent version numbers. I've created a [demo repository](https://github.com/benjaminyakobi/demotwo/releases) and as you can see, the release numbers are `...38,39,40,47,49`. I didn't find any solution for this in [GitHub Actions Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions).

I want to have consistent incrementally growing version numbers or even a `v.x.x` structure if it's possible.

My complete workflow can be found [here](https://github.com/benjaminyakobi/demotwo/blob/main/.github/workflows/firebase.yml), my `release-project` job is:

```
...previous jobs: build, test, deploy...
release-project:
    name: Release project
    needs: deploy-project
    ...
      - name: Create release
        id: create_release_id
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.run_number }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.run_number }}
      - name: Upload release asset
        id: upload-release-asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release_id.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./project.zip
          asset_name: project-v${{ github.run_number }}.zip
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not relying on `run_number` and using the **latest tag** from the repo to generate the next version based on it. For example, you can use the [Get Latest Tag](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-latest-tag), [Next SemVers](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/next-semvers), and [Next Monotonic Release version](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/next-monotonic-release-version) GH Actions.

**Semantic versioning workflow:**

```
...

jobs:
  test-next-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # required for github-action-get-previous-tag

      - name: Get previous tag
        id: previoustag
        uses: 'WyriHaximus/github-action-get-previous-tag@v1'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Get next minor version
        id: semver
        uses: 'WyriHaximus/github-action-next-semvers@v1'
        with:
          version: ${{ steps.previoustag.outputs.tag }}

      - name: Create release
        id: create_release_id
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.semver.outputs.patch }}
          release_name: Release ${{ steps.semver.outputs.patch }}
```

**Consecutive numbers versioning workflow:**

```
...

jobs:
  test-next-release-custom:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # required for github-action-get-previous-tag

      - name: Get Previous tag
        id: previoustag
        uses: 'WyriHaximus/github-action-get-previous-tag@v1'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          
      - name: Get next version
        id: next
        uses: 'WyriHaximus/github-action-next-release-version@1.0.0'
        with:
          version: ${{ steps.previoustag.outputs.tag }}

      - name: Create release
        id: create_release_id
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.next.outputs.version }}
          release_name: Release ${{ steps.next.outputs.version }}
```